# What is the correct way to express a path in order to get Pelican generated html to link to an image?

Tags: html, pelican

I'm just starting to create a blog with Pelican and wanted to link to an image. I did this by including the following line in my Markdown file:

```
<img src="./myImg1a.png" alt="./myImg.png" style="width: 750px; height: 800px;"/>
```

This line was successfully reproduced in the html file, which Pelican placed in the output directory (i.e. */myBlog/output*). I placed the png files in the output directory (i.e. the same directory as the html files and got the following error:

```
WARNING:root:Unable to find file /category/myImg1a.png/index.html or variations.
```

where  */category* refers to *myBlog/output/category*. When I, instead, used the following html code:

```
<img src="/myImg1a.png" alt="/myImg.png" style="width: 750px; height: 800px;"/>
```

everything worked fine. I don't understand why this should be:

1. If the image file is in the same directory as the html file, shouldn't "./myImg1.png" be correct and "/myImg.png" be incorrect?
2. Why was the folder */category/myImg1a.png/index.html* being sought at all?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: @Raj - No. I did not. Now, I just need to get this comment over 15 characters, so it will post.....

Comment: Thanks!  The things we must do to make systems work sometimes....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, **by design**, you should not change the contents of the `output` directly/manually.
You should put all your static contents in separate directory which is usually named as `images` or `paths`. And, then configure the path(s) in `pelicanconf.py` as:

```
# ...
PATH = 'content'
STATIC_PATHS = ['images', 'files']  # add any no. of locations
# ...
```

In that case, when Pelican is building actual page, it will look for any referenced static file in `./content/images` and `./content/files` locations. If cannot find there, it will emit the error message.

**Now, answering to your trouble ...**

By,

```
... src="./myImg1a.png" ...
```

`Pelican` look for this `myImg1a.png` file in your `myBlog/content/` folder as you are mentioning `./` which is the root folder for `Pelican` is working on.

But, when you are referring it as

```
... src="/myImg1a.png" ...
```

`Pelican` eventually finds it in the `html` file's directory. By getting `/` as location, `Pelican` is looking for it in the same directory of your `myblog/my-blog-post/index.html` which is `myblog/my-blog-post/`.
Hence, working. But not in the ideal way.

For a deeper understanding, please take a look into Pelican's documentation [on this matter](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/content.html#linking-to-static-files).

> 2. Why was the folder /category/myImg1a.png/index.html being sought at all?

`Pelican`, here, just trying to be smart.