# How can I link the static profile.jpg image to all the Pelican files?

Tags: python, pelican

I am trying to set up my `AVATAR` variable in the pelican-bootstap-theme bur I get the following error:

```
WARNING:root:Unable to find `/pages/images/blog/profile.jpg` or variations.
```

My project's filesystem looks like this:

```
content
├── post1.md
├── post2.md
├── images
│    └──blog
│       ├── banner.png
│       ├── favicon.jpg
│       └── profile.jpg
└── pages
    └── about.md
```

And I have tried to use both within the `pelicanconf.py` file:

```
AVATAR = './images/blog/profile.jpg'

AVATAR = '/images/blog/profile.jpg'

AVATAR = '/content/images/blog/profile.jpg'
```

Which is what I red in this other SO question: [What is the correct way to express a path in order to get Pelican generated html to link to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28257113/what-is-the-correct-way-to-express-a-path-in-order-to-get-pelican-generated-html).

So the problem is that the profile image (`AVATAR` variable) is show correctly in the blog post: given that pelican goes to `/images/blog/profile.jpg` where is the image actually. But when loading a page from `/pages` it uses the route above.

Finally, my pelican's conf uses this paths:

```
 PATH = 'content'
 STATIC_PATHS = ['images']
```

**EDIT:** I have removed `images/blog` from `STATIC_PATHS`, following the advise of @ScottCarpenter.

Also I have tried to add the same image at the `about.md` file using the following line

```
![Avatar image]({attach}images/blog/profile.jpg)
```

The result is the same that when using it inside the pelican-bootstrap3 theme template. This time with this warning message.

```
WARNING:root:Unable to find `/pages/{attach}images/blog/profile.jpg` or variations.
```

Comment: How are you referencing things in your template files?

Comment: I use the [pelican-bootstrap3](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-themes/tree/master/pelican-bootstrap3) theme, here you can see the template: [link](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-themes/blob/b6ddae910c53ddd7a556ed339e6d66e5d3064b4b/pelican-bootstrap3/templates/includes/aboutme.html) @ScottCarpenter

Comment: Ah... I misunderstood and thought you had modified something. Just tried out the theme with an avatar and don't see an issue, using something like `AVATAR = '/images/test/test.jpg'`, where images is in my static_paths list. I don't know that this is a problem, but you don't need to specify `images/blog` as a static path since it will be included under the images path. Also interesting that you're seeing that WARNING message. My site builds with no warning, no matter what I put as the value for AVATAR.

Comment: I have edited the main post @ScottCarpenter, I seems like the problem does not only affect the `AVATAR` variable itself, but all the static files linked.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the theme you're using, you will need to look at the index.html or base.html file and figure out what variables (which it will search for in your publishconf.py file) or local destinations your theme searches for at rendering time. I use the Flex theme, which has this html in the base.html file for the image that sits in the profile area:

```
<aside>
<div>
  <a href="{{ SITEURL }}">
    {% if SITELOGO %}
    <img src="{{ SITELOGO }}" alt="{{ SITETITLE }}" title="{{ SITETITLE }}">
    {% else %}
    <img src="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ THEME_STATIC_DIR }}/img/profile.png" alt="{{ SITETITLE }}" title="{{ SITETITLE }}">
    {% endif %}
  </a>
```

So, the theme is expecting a variable called `SITELOGO` to contain the picture destination. I added an images folder to my content folder, and added a `SITELOGO` variable with the image location to publishconf.py, like follows:

```
PATH = 'content'
STATIC_PATHS = ['images']
SITELOGO = 'images/profile.jpg'
```

And that solves the problem for my theme, at least.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
content
├── post1.md
├── post2.md
├── siteImages
│    └──profile.png
```

and using the pelican-theme alchemy this works for me:

```
SITEIMAGE = '/siteImages/profile.png'
THEME = 'themes/alchemy'
PATH = 'content'
STATIC_PATHS  = ['siteImages']
```